# Corda: Upgraded contract with Backward compatiblity

Tags: corda

I have 4 nodes named alice, bob, John and Jane. All were running cordApp with contract version1. Now contract upgraded on alice and bob node using Explicit contract upgrade along with flow upgrade. How can i make sure that both alice and bob can commmunicate with others using old flow + contract (Backward compatible).

Can i get demonstration of Implicit contract upgradation as well...

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to upgrade the contract see : https://docs.corda.net/contract-upgrade.html#workflow

``` 10. Each counterparty (the ``Acceptor``s) verifies the proposal, signs or rejects the state reissuance accordingly, and sends a signature or rejection notification back to the initiating node ```

If somehow the contract is installed manually, the contract cordapp hashes would also be different throwing an exception.